# Is it possible to make a non-locking Windows share (files that other people use remotely don't get locked)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares

The subject pretty much says it.

I'm a developer and at my workplace I've developed a little internal application that me and some of my colleagues are using from time to time. To make the latest version available to them I've shared the folder where the compilation results are. However this means that whenever they are using it I cannot compile it anymore - the files are locked.

Is there any way to share a folder, but disallow remote people from locking files? The files are already read-only to them anyway. Perhaps there is another solution that would serve my purposes?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to replace executable code while other people are actively running that code?

Comment: @Blackbeagle - Well... yes. :D OK, so I guess that's a bit extreme, but at the same time I would like them to get the latest version "automatically" the next time they run it. OK, I guess ClickOnce is a solution, though feels a bit like an overkill. :P

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [UseOpportunisticLocking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775627%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters`. There are several additional parameters in there that maybe of interest.

However may I ask why you choose to distribute this way? without knowing what your application is written in I can only take guesses as to why you would chose to distribute in this way.

If you wrote a .NET Application (I think you need at least 3.5?) might I suggest you take a look at [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) from the MSDN:

> ClickOnce is a deployment technology that enables you to create self-updating Windows-based applications that can be installed and run with minimal user interaction.

I have used ClickOnce for several of our internal applications with great success, its auto updater is very powerful and requires little additional code (just bumping the assembly version and clicking 'Deploy').

However there are some pitfalls to this, specifically we ran into an issue for an application that required elevated UAC rights. Programs which require this are not supported by ClickOnce Deployment.

Comment: I distribute it like this because it's a simple way to distribute. Yes, it's a .NET 3.5 app, so I could use ClickOnce with it. Though I'm afraid I might forget to Deploy it when I change it. :P But it's a worthy idea, I'll keep it in mind!

Comment: Sorry if that came out wrong, I still distribute via file shares (in cases where I can't use ClickOnce), but when I found ClickOnce that was a huge life saver and I cringe when I can't use it :)!

Answer (score 0):

How large is it, and is that a limiting factor? i.e., Is there a reason you don't just create a mirrored copy (sync) so that they are using a different copy than you are?

[SyncToy v2.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52) is a simple, free sync tool that should be able to replicate your data no problem.

Comment: I could, it's not big (below 20MB), but what and when would sync it?

Comment: Link to 'what' added above. As to 'when,' that's determined by how you configure it.